# Pi-Zero can't boot past the user login screen - "Perpetual Login"

Tags: raspbian, linux, display, pi-zero, login

I have a pi-zero which I was most recently trying to install OpenSSL-1.0.2r on that wouldn't start up. I fixed the issue already by swapping out the SD card but I'm still not sure why the problem came up in the first place..

What would happen was I would boot up the pi to the login screen where it would ask for my username and password and then I would enter them in correctly. However, after a few seconds of a blank screen during which I assume the pi was attempting to load the desktop, the pi would just return to the same login screen and ask for my username and password again. Rebooting didn't work and ultimately I swapped out the SD card which did work

My question, basically, is if anyone else has run into this problem or knows why it happens? I'm very interested in avoiding this in the future.
I hope my question is clear enough!

Comment: perhaps it was a faulty SD card or you did something wrong™

Comment: Any ideas of what it is that I did wrong?

Comment: no, because you have given no information, no logs, no details at all :p

Comment: I do apologize but I aimed this question more towards people who might have had the same issue. I don't really know what information one would need to figure this out anyways tbh

Comment: These problems are usually caused by misuse of `sudo chown ...` or `sudo chmod ...` commands. The other common cause is `sudo startx`. Do you see a pattern here? Don't use `sudo` unless you really need to run something with root privileges.

Comment: If you have a USB microSD card reader, you can boot the Pi with the working card, insert the non-working card in the reader, mount the file system, then go check /var/log.  Ttry `ls -latr` which will list files sorted by time, but reversed (newest files listed last.   You can use `tail` to view the ends of the files for the most recent messages and may get clues as to why your Pi was stuck.

Comment: any issue I've ever had with a pi malfunctioning stemmed from faulty SD card - so, while I can't say I've had exactly the same issue, it's hard to say, because the issue you described is so vague